# Configure nexus repository to only store jars that are installed (selected by me)

Tags: maven, jar, nexus

I would like to configure a nexus repository to only manage jars that I install. Right now it also retrieves jars from maven central and stores them in the repository. I don't want that to happen. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

When you say to store the "jars that are installed" , if you are referring to the artifacts being created by your project, you can have a hosted maven repository snapshot/release and use maven deploy plugin to upload it on to your nexus repository.
You can either create a profile in your pom and activate in your install it on mvn install phase to upload the artifacts to your nexus repository.

Comment: Hi Adnan,
First of thank you for your input. I will try to explain better what i want. Is it possible to configure a nexus server to only store the jars i install. Right now i also brings in third part jar from maven central. I just want the jars i install in nexus to be stored in the repository. /nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage should only contains the jars install and not jars that are also downloaded from central.

Comment: Yes it is possible to have a nexus repository to host only the jars created  by you. You need to create a maven hosted repository and make changes in your pom.xml and settings.xml to have the artifacts getting generated in your maven build to be uploaded on nexus. you can find details on how to this on this link http://www.baeldung.com/maven-deploy-nexus